# Program Arcade Games: Ch 16 Worksheet 2D-Array Algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, programming-challenge, pygame

The `check_celebrity()` function below takes an `n*n` grid as its parameter and prints the celebrity if there is one.

A celebrity is a person who is known by everybody but doesn't know anybody except himself.

If `grid [ i ] [ j ]` equals 1,  "i" knows "j".
If `grid [ i ] [ j ]` equals 0,  "i" doesn't know "j".

However, I am not satisfied with this one because there are too many loops inside loops and if checks. Are there any ways I can improve it?

```py
def check_celebrity(grid):
    known = 0
    unknown = 0


    for i in range(len(grid)):
       ## Reset these variable for every person i
        known = 0
        unknown = 0
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            if grid[i][j] == 0:
                unknown += 1

            ## if he doesn't know anybody,
            ## check if every other "j" knows him
            if unknown == len(grid)-1:
                for j in range(len(grid)):
                    if grid[j][i] == 1:
                        known += 1

                    if known == len(grid):
                        print("#{} is the one.".format(i))
                        break
```

```py
#These can be used as test cases

##  0 is a celebrity.
grid = [ [1, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, 1, 0] ]

## 2 is a celebrity
grid = [ [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 1, 1, 1] ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Benchmarks

Before we make changes, I'll measure the time taken  by the `check_celebrity()`
function executed `i` times on a `5x5` grid

Note that I have made a small change, I am returning the celebrity ID rather than printing to cut the cost of `print()`

```py
#   Number of iterations   |   Time taken (seconds)
#  ---------------------------------------------
#        10 ^ 5            |      0.385
#        10 ^ 6            |      3.428
#        10 ^ 7            |      35.049
```

---

## Use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Compared to using `.format()`, Python-3 has [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) which provide a nicer way of formatting strings

```py
print(f"{i} is the one")
```

---

## [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

```py
    known = 0
    unknown = 0

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        known = 0
        unknown = 0
```

You are going to initialize `known, unknown`  with `0` in the loop anyway, why do it again outside the loop?

```py
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        ## Reset these variable for every person i
        known = 0
        unknown = 0
```

---

## Use a tuple

Since you don't need to modify `grid`, shift to a tuple as  [it will be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340539/why-is-tuple-faster-than-list-in-python)

---

## Optimize #1

```py
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            if grid[i][j] == 0:
                unknown += 1

            ## if he doesn't know anybody,
            ## check if every other "j" knows him
            if unknown == len(grid)-1
```

The second condition will only be true if the first one is also true because the value of `unknown` remains the same if the first condition evaluates to false. The question says that

> if grid [ i ][ j ] == 1 , i knows j

If `i` knows `j` and `i != j`, we can be certain that `i` isn't our celebrity, so we can directly skip this loop and go to the next person - `break`.

```py
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            if (grid[i][j] == 1) and (i != j):
                break

            unknown += 1
```

---

## Optimize #2

Out of the two conditions, we have already checked one. So now all we need to do is check the other one. if either of those conditions fails, we immediately exit the loop. If the whole inner loop has been iterated through without anything failing, then `j == len(grid-1)`, so at the end, we check for this, if it's true we return `i`.

```py
def check_celebrity(grid):
    r = range(len(grid))
    for i in r:
        is_celeb = True
        for j in r:
            if (grid[i][j] == 1) and (i != j):
                break
            if (grid[j][i] == 0) and (i != j):
                break

        if j == len(grid)-1: return i
```

Smashed into one statement

```py
def check_celebrity(grid):
    r = range(len(grid))
    for i in r:
        for j in r:
            if (i != j and (( not grid[j][i]) or (grid[i][j] == 1))):
                break

        if j == len(grid)-1: return i
```

---

## Test

I will use the 4 tests given on the [website](http://programarcadegames.com/worksheets/show_file.php?file=worksheet_16.php) 
I designed a simple function to do this

```py
def test(grid, test_no,correct_answer):
    print(f"Test number {test_no} \nCorrect answer: {correct_answer}")
    print(f"Returned answer: #{check_celebrity(grid)}\n\n")
```

Tests

```py
grid1 = [ [1, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, 1, 1] ]

test(grid1, 1, "#2")
```

```py
grid2 = [ [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
         [1, 0, 0, 1, 1] ]
test(grid2, 2, "#None")
```

```py
grid3 = [ [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 1, 1, 1] ]
test(grid3, 3, "#2")
```

```py
grid4 = [ [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 1, 1, 1] ]

test(grid4, 4, "#None")
```

Results

```
Test number 1
Correct answer: #2
Returned answer: #2


Test number 2
Correct answer: #None
Returned answer: #None


Test number 3
Correct answer: #2
Returned answer: #2


Test number 4
Correct answer: #None
Returned answer: #None
```

- Grids are copy-pasted from the original question, hence they are `[[]]` and not `(())`. I will switch to tuples for the **new** code

---

## Comparison

### Old

```py
#   Number of iterations   |   Time taken (s)
#  ---------------------------------------------
#        10 ^ 5            |      0.385
#        10 ^ 6            |      3.428
#        10 ^ 7            |      35.049
```

### New

```py
#   Number of iterations   |   Time taken (s)
#  ---------------------------------------------
#        10 ^ 5            |      0.256
#        10 ^ 6            |      1.815
#        10 ^ 7            |      17.518
```

```py
def check_celebrity(grid):
    r = range(len(grid))
    for i in r:
        for j in r:
            if (i != j and (( not grid[j][i]) or (grid[i][j] == 1))):
                break

        if j == len(grid)-1: return i

grid  = ( (1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
          (0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
          (0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
          (0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
          (1, 0, 1, 1, 1) )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed improvements. This solution always works whenever there is just one "1" at the position where `"i" == "j"` regardless of the ones or zeros on that column. That is, the loop just checks if " i " knows anybody and not the other way around. For example if you change `grid2[3][2]` to 0, it will still work although it shouldn't because that means there is someone who doesn't know `"i"`. Therefore, I think there must be another if check for the column in the first loop.  Please correct me if I am wrong or missing something. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @Bilgili I tested it with all cases on the website, it works just as expected.

Comment: Okay, I gave it a second try by copying and pasting your code under the **New** heading and the following grid from the website which is the 2nd test: `grid = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 0, 0, 1, 1] ]`. There is no celebrity here but the function returns #2 as a celebrity. I can't see what I am missing. Could you please clarify this for me?

Comment: @Bilgili Please check my new answer, you are right. I made a horrible, stupid mistake, really sorry about that. I have updated the answer and the benchmarks, I hope everything is alright now :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Code Review, few suggestions:

- Instead of calling `.format()` you can use f-Strings: `print(f"#{i} is the one.")`
- Is better to return the result, instead of printing in the method and `break`
- You can use `all()` to test the celebrity and make the code more compact.

Applying the suggestions:

```py
def check_celebrity(grid):
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        # Check if i is a candidate celebrity
        if grid[i][i] == 1 and grid[i].count(1) == 1:
            # Ensure that i is a celebrity
            if all(grid[j][i] == 1 for j in range(len(grid))):
                return i
```

Test:

```py
grid = [ [1, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, 1, 0] ]

print(f"#{check_celebrity(grid)} is the one.")
# Outputs: #0 is a celebrity
```